# How to put custom image after cast device is connected from sender application? (android app)

Tags: android, chromecast

i have used Media Router for casting my app and i want to change the screen after connection to chromecast device just like that of youtube(reference).How can i achieve that?

[i want like this image but that image will be my own](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi6Es.jpg)

[Now it shows this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZafq.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose to use the Cast SDK for casting, then you can write your own custom receiver or use a Styled Receiver and provide a home image and a few more styling parameters.

Comment: Yes I did thank you.. Now I have another problem after I connect to cast device i get the mini controller at the bottom of the activity but when i click on it is should open the VideoCastControllerActivity but it does not and instead going inside onFailed method.

Comment: It would be useful to know what the "onFailed reports, also turn on logging (set DEBUG=true in LogUtils) in CCL and provide the log. Did you remember to add the VideoCastControllerActivity to your manifest?

Comment: Thank you i had forgotten to add it in the manifest part that was the reason for not opening.

Comment: I have already declared VideoCastControllerActivity in manifest but the main problem is: 1. I open LocalPlayerActivity 2. I play video in videoview 3. Then i connect to cast device 4. connection is established 5. In this case VideoCastControllerActivity does not open up. It goes inside onApplicationConnected block as well but it nothing happens.. :( But if i 1st connect to the cast device in the activity that is step ahead of this LocalPlayerActivity and then i come to localPlayerActivity and if i play it shows up the VideoCastControllerActivity and everything works fine in this case

Comment: I have migrated from v2 to v3 and i am having the problem as asked in this question.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502173/chromecast-doesnt-play-hls-in-m3u8-format)