# ChromeCast doesnt play HLS in .m3u8 format

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

Integrated chromecast in the app. Everything works fine except it does not play live streaming url which is in .m3u8 format  but plays .m3u8 format url for movies. I am doing this to set url to chromecast.

```
return new MediaInfo.Builder(url)
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)
            .setContentType("videos/mp4")
            .setMetadata(movieMetadata)
            .setStreamDuration(mVideoView.getDuration())
            .build();
```

Comment: Make sure your [CORS](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player) is enabled, and enable your logging in the chrome [debugging](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging) session to see the logs. As Ali's suggestion in a related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34887826/unable-to-play-live-stream-on-chromecast-from-android-sender-app), "hard-code the url of your stream in CastVideos-android app and see if that works." Lastly, streaming media requires the [Cast Media Player Library](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player) to be used.

Answer (score 3):

According to google Cast Samples, needed MIME Types are shown in json file
https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/f.json

```
{
    "type": "hls",
    "mime": "application/x-mpegurl",
},
{
    "type": "dash",
    "mime": "application/dash+xml",
},
{
    "type": "mp4",
    "mime": "videos/mp4",
}
```